# Unclear nested lambda compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Visual Studio 2013. This line:

```
void main()
{
    auto f = [](std::string const& a){ return [a](std::string const& b) { return a == b; }; };
}
```

causes a compile error:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_2de76b925b1cf5057c3b0fda7d008552>::()::<lambda_c01227249c973bad6dd44317ca85b677>' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(const std::string &)'
```

Is it a bug or the my folly?

Edit:
May be it will usefull for somebody: [case on Microsoft site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808696/build-failed-when-one-lambda-without-the-specified-return-value-returns-another-lambda).
Workaround is explicit return type definition for external lambda:

```
auto f = [](std::string const& a)->std::function<bool(std::string const&)>{ return [a](std::string const& b) { return a == b; }; };
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, GCC and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab5cac423a49d3c1) compile it just fine.

Comment: Yes, gcc (i have 4.8.1) compiles with no problem.

Comment: Note: the return type deduction (for lambda-expressions) applies the function-to-pointer conversion, that's probably what MSVC is struggling with: There's no function-to-pointer conversion for lambdas with capture.